# passing data from an api into a html file

Tags: api, https

So I am using openweather api to get weather data, and I want to send the data into a html file or maybe a js file that is embeded with the html, but i don't know how I can do this. Here is the code that i got so far

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto &appid=apikey&units=metric";
 https.get(url,function(response){
    response.on("data",function(data){
    const weatherData=JSON.parse(data);
    var temp=weatherData.main.temp;
    var describtion=weatherData.weather[0].description;
    var icon=weatherData.weather[0].icon;
    var imgURL="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png";


    res.write("<p>The weather is "+ describtion + "</p>");
    res.write("<h1>The temperature in " +"Toronto is "+ temp + " celcius</h1>");
    res.write("<img src="+imgURL+">");


    });
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
});
```

I would like to pass the temp, describtion and img url and shows in the html when the user sends a get request and it shows the weather in Toronto by default without a post request. Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you trying to do this entirely in browser-side JavaScript without server code?  Then you would use AJAX and more JavaScript to update the current page once you get a response.

Comment: im trying to remove the res.write part and display them inside the index.html file, but i don't know how i would pass the vaiables into a html file or a js file